# How to fix: "https.proxyHost set to 127.0.0.1" in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, http-proxy

I got a warning in Android studio 1.3.2 : 
[image]

And I can NOT down third party projects by gradle, How can I fix this ?